# Trouble comparing dates

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am having a problem with the following code that is supposed to print a message if a given day is today or tomorrow:

```
if (dayOfMonth >= Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH){
     System.out.printl("Is today or tomorrow");
}
```

If `dayOfMonth` is greater or equal to today's date, the message is printed. However, the condition always returns false. I found out that `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` returns 5, but I have no idea why.

Todays date is 14-03-2015, so `dayOfMonth` should be 14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` does not represent the day of the month, it is a constant value that is used to *retrieve* the day of month like this :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

By the way, your code to check if a date is today or tomorrow does not work when tomorrow is the first day of the next month (because `calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` will return 1). You also need the current month to determine if a given date is the same day or the next day.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
if (month == calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) && 
    dayOfMonth == calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
    //day is today
} else {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    if (month + 1 == calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) && dayOfMonth == 1 ||
        month == calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) && dayOfMonth + 1 == calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
        //day is tomorrow
    }
}
```

Using Java 8, this can be simplified to (where `myDate` is a `LocalDate`)

```
LocalDate tomorrow = LocalDate.now().addDays(1);
if (Duration.between(myDate.atTime(0, 0), tomorrow.atTime(0, 0)).toDays() <= 1) {
    //is today or tomorrow
}
```

Comment: yeah I already had those issues solved but thanks anyways. I dont know wich version of java android studio uses.

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` is one of many [calendar fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#field.detail) (`Calendar.YEAR`, `Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR`, `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH`, etc.) that you can use in the `Calendar.set()` and `Calendar.get()` methods.

The reason why `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` is equal to 5 is because it is merely the integer used internally within the implementation of the `java.util.Calendar` class to represent the `DAY_OF_MONTH` field. The value of that integer isn't actually important to the user.

If you're interested, you can actually see the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Calendar.java) yourself:

```
/**
 * Field number for <code>get</code> and <code>set</code> indicating the
 * day of the month. This is a synonym for <code>DATE</code>.
 * The first day of the month has value 1.
 *
 * @see #DATE
 */
public final static int DAY_OF_MONTH = 5;
```

In your case, you'd want to do something like

```
Calendar myCal = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfMonth = myCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

to get the actual day of month value you're interested in.

For more info, the documentation for java.util.Calendar can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).